# Should R package functions not include comments?

Tags: r, r-package, cran

I'm in the process of creating a small R package containing a set of functions that should be useful in a specialized area of Biology. I currently have the package on GitHub, but want to submit it to CRAN soon. One thing I have noticed when digging around in other packages, is that the code often includes no comments at all (e.g. short comments describing what different parts of the code does), which makes it more difficult to understand. I'm not a programmer or expert in R, so I don't understand why comments are often not included, and Hadley Wickham's "R packages" book makes not mention of this.

Edit: I'm not referring to the object documentation, that one accesses with `?function()`, but to comments that are interspersed within the function code, which a normal user wouldn't see, but that could be helpful for people trying to figure out exactly how a function works.

Is there a specific reason to not include comments within the functions of an R package? If so, should I remove all the comments from my code before submitting to CRAN?

Comment: Documentation is key. IMO, the standard is to make small functions that you can document in the style like https://r-pkgs.org/man.html explains. The smaller the function, the less comments within, the more useful is it for the user when he calls  eg. `?bio_function()`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Stephan. I realize my question was somewhat unclear, and have updated it to better explain what I'm asking.

Comment: I understand your concern. In general when you have a very small function with a good documentation, you don't need comments within the function. the "person trying to figure out how it works" will understand based on the documentation. Small functions can be added together in other small functions that also have nice documentation. I assume thats the reason, why there is no "comment explanation". When my colleagues review my code, its easier for them to have a good function documentation than several comments above or behind my code.

Comment: Probably you might find that useful? https://style.tidyverse.org/functions.html#comments-1 and https://style.tidyverse.org/documentation.html

Comment: Aha, now I understand you. That's a fair point which makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you "digging around in other packages?" Comments will be stripped out of the code when the package is built, so what you see from `dplyr:::equal_data_frame` (executed from the console) and https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/R/all-equal.r#L84 won't be quite the same.

Comment: That helps to explains things @Benjamin. Thinking of it, I noted never seeing comments in functions when looking inside R, e.g. `dplyr:::equal_data_frame`, but sometimes seeing it in GitHub (for some packages yes, for others no). I didn't know comments are removed when packages are built, so that makes sense.